How to stop followers from dissenting
In Cult of the Lamb, a follower may occasionally dissent if faith is low enough.
What are good ways to stop them dissenting, and have them return to the cult? Reeducating them daily just doesn’t do it.

There are a few ways that dissenters can be dealt with:

Re-education - The Lamb can speak to the dissenter while holding open a book to try and raise their faith. Re-education can be performed once a day. Attempting to re-educate a dissenter again in the same day will result in the dissenter saying "I have already heard enough of your lies for one day! We will continue our argument tomorrow."

Prison - When in Prison, dissenters cannot spread falsehood and their faith increases faster when being re-educated. Other followers may occasionally mock the imprisoned individual. Disciple followers can re-educate Dissenters.

Killing them - Dissenters can be sacrificed or ascended like normal followers or executed via the "Murder Follower" action.

Food - Feeding them a Magnificent Mixed Meal is guaranteed to make them stop dissenting instantly. Minced Follower Meat can also make them stop dissenting but it only has a 40% chance and has a 75% chance to make them sick. Alternatively, they can be fed a Deadly Dish which has a 75% chance of instantly killing them, making it an alternative to using rituals or the "Murder follower" action.

Spending coins - If a dissenter leaving is unavoidable, keeping coins low makes it so dissenters won't steal as much when they leave. Buy things with your coins, or convert the coins into gold bars with a refinery.


